# equation of the tangent line to the given curve

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Find an equation of the tangent line to the given curve at the specified points:

$F(t)=(t+1, t^2, 2t - 1)$ at the point $(2,1,1)$

Teacher said the we should start like that:

$r(t) = f(t) + t  df/dt(t)$

```
 = A    + V
```

So:
    $F(t)=(t+1,t^2,2t -1)$

$(2,1,1)=(t+1,t^2,2t -1)$

( But I have no idea what to do)

Comment: I'm guessing that's a system of parameterized equations?  $x = t+1$, $y = t^2$, $z = 2t - 1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write $r(t) = f(t) + t  df/dt(t)$ is correct though one must be careful, since one must actually evaluate $df/dt$ at the point $f(t)$. In your example of the point $(2,1,1)$ the first coordinate of $f(t)$ is $t+1$ which is to match the first coordinate $2$ of the point. Thus you have the numerical value of $df/dt(2)$ to use, and since $df/dt=(1,2t,2)$ and $t=1$ you get $df/dt(2)=(1,2,2).$ So your tangent line, using the formula, is 
$$r(t)=(2,1,1)+t(1,2,2)=(2+t,1+2t,1+2t).$$

What I mean about "being careful" is that for say a one variable function $y=f(x)$ one can say the tangent line equation is $y-y_0=f'(x_0)\cdot(x-x_0)$, but often students forget to actually plug in a specific value for $x$ and just leave $f'(x)$ where it should be $f'(x_0),$ which results usually in a nonlinear equation for the tangent line.